# Batch | if NOT %var% == String | not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have a bit of a problem with my Batch program. It's simple and I intend to have it display an output, but only when it doesn't equal something. But.. I'm running into problems. Here's my current code;

NOTE: It's modified to hide sensitive information as well as get rid of unrelated code.

```
@echo off
TITLE //
set mode=0
set output=Surrr

:WORKSTATION
cls
if statements here //
echo.
if NOT "%output%"=="Surrr" (
    echo %output%
    set output=Surrr )

if statements //

set /p "i="
if /I %i%==FTP (
    goto FTP )
if /I %i%==RDP (
    goto RDP )
if /I %i%==HTML (
    set mode=1 
    goto WORKSTATION )
if /I %i%==GAMEMAKER (
    set mode=2 
    goto WORKSTATION )
if /I %i%==EXIT (
    exit
    goto WORKSTATION
 ) else (
     set output=Invalid Input
     goto WORKSTATION )

unrelated code //
```

Now, when I type an input that doesn't work, it sets the output to "Invalid Input" and displays it, as it should. The problem is when I type in a valid input, the word is reset to "Surrr" but isn't picked up by the `if NOT` statement. Henceforth display "Surrr" when it shouldn't.

I generally at a standstill. Any suggestions/ideas to overcome this problem?
Anything will help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should "quote your string assignments" - thus:

```
set "output=Surrr"
```

The problem with a statement like

```
...
set output=Surrr )
```

is that the space is included in the value assigned, so `"%output%"` will be Surrr<kbd>Space</kbd>, not `Surrr` as you may be decieved into thinking by an debugging `echo` (which is why when debugging I tend to `echo` value with a series of `+++` either end thus `echo +++%output%+++` - it makes the invisible spaces obvious)

You should also use (eg)

```
if /I "%i%"=="HTML" (
```

for preference when dealing with user-input. If the user types spaces or commas in the response, quoting the input ensures that the `if` statement is syntactically correct (not bullet-proof, but deals with many user-input-errors)